# SQL Dsum based on criteria

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to sum all amounts where column 'weight'=2 and do so according to months and format it in dollar currency. Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
Format([Final Action Date],"yyyy-mm") AS [Month], 
DSum("[Amount]","C02: Underwriting Audit Case Detail Report Record Selection"," [Weight] = '2'") AS FA_Critical, 
Sum(IIf([Weight]="2",1,0)) AS Critical_Count

FROM [C02: Underwriting Audit Case Detail Report Record Selection]
WHERE ((([C02: Underwriting Audit Case Detail Report Record Selection].[Case Type]) Not In ("**Target IUP")))
GROUP BY Format([Final Action Date],"yyyy-mm");
```

Here is the result that I have so far:

```
Month   FA_Critical Critical_Count
2015-01 2035480     2
2015-02 2035480     2
2015-03 2035480     0
2015-04 2035480     1
```

Here is what I want:

```
Month   FA_Critical Critical_Count
2015-01 $1,350,000  2
2015-02 $510,480    2
2015-03 $0          0
2015-04 $175,000    1
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Here is a better presentation of my tables:

Comment: This is Access right?

Comment: @mxix I expect you are right (no `DSUM` in SQL Server) so retagging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the criteria for your DSum, it's looking at [Weight]='2' across the whole recordset, which is why you are getting the same value for all 4 records. The DSUM is not partitioned by the GROUP BY the same way that the SUM is.

Use a SUM instead of the DSUM, and instead of using 1,0 for true and false, use the value of your amount column:

```
Sum(IIf([Weight]="2",[Amount],0)) AS FA_Critical
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - really appreciate it. I'm not that good in sql - could you please tell me why Access comes up with an error message: "Subqueries cannot be used in the expression (IIf[Weight]="2",[Amount],0))       What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are both [Weight] and [Amount] columns? or is Amount derived? I can only go on the snippet of the code you prepared, and you don't have any raw data. My expression is assuming that each is a column and not also an expression.

Comment: @Robert  Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry you guys. I was so exited to continue with my project that forgot my manners. Thanks you guys so much for your input. it helped me a great deal!